# jqgrid inline cell editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with inline cell editing. I have my grid setup like this

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: function (postdata) {
            },
            gridview: true,
            cellEdit: true,
            //cellurl is not used, but its required. should do more research.
            cellurl: '',
            beforeSaveCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                UpdateCell(cellname, value);
            }
        });
```

I am saving the data in the cell using beforeSaveCell. I don't want to use cellurl. But when I don't give cellurl, I get an error "url is not provided". how can i save the cell data without actually using the cellurl if there is?

Answer (score 0):

I just added cellSubmit: 'clientArray' to the grid properties. This way I can save using the beforeSaveCell method and remove the cellurl property.